# App renavigates to the logIn Page even if a new JWT token is regenerated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cookies

I am generating an accessToken for a user upon Login and a refreshToken
which helps to regenerate another accessToken for the user
if the user trys to refresh a page or the token times out.
but the problem is though these tokens are generated as it should be,
I am always redirected to Login page when I refresh the page
or when I click to access another Tab in the menue. What could
be the problem here.

```
//here is the Routes

const App = () => {
  return (

    <Routes>
      <Route path='registerPage' element={<RegisterPage />} />

      <Route path='logIn' element={<LogInPage />} />
      
      {/* Protected Routes */}
      <Route element={<PersistLogIn/>}>
      <Route element={<RequireAuth />}>

        <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>

          <Route index element={<Home />} />

          <Route path='dashboard' element={<HomeLayOutt />} />

          <Route path='moneyIn' element={<MoneyIn />} />

          <Route path='moneyOut' element={<MoneyOut />} />
          <Route path='inventory' element={<Inventory />} />
    </Route> 
    </Route>
 </Routes>


//LogIn Page

const LogInPage = () => {
    const [username, setUserName] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassWord] = useState("")
    const {setAuth} = useAuth()


    const handleUser_Name =(e)=>{
        setUserName(e.target.value)
      }
      const handlePass_word = (e)=>{
        setPassWord(e.target.value)
      }
    
    const location = useLocation()

    const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || '/'

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const goToRegister =()=>navigate('/registerPage')

        const handleLogIn=()=>{
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3500/auth', JSON.stringify({username, password}),
          {
            headers:{'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
            withCredentials: true
          }
        )
        .then(res=> {    
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res?.data))
            console.log((res?.data))
            const accessToken = res?.data?.accessToken
            setAuth({username, password, accessToken})

            setUserName('')
            setPassWord('')

            navigate(from, {replace: true})
            
        }).catch(err =>{console.log(err)})
    }
}

//Context API(AuthProvider)

import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({})

export const AuthProvider =({children})=>{
   const [auth, setAuth] = useState({})
   console.log(auth)

  return(
  <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth, setAuth}}>
    {children}
   </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default AuthContext

//useAuth

import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () =>{
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}
export default useAuth

//RequireAuth

import {useLocation, Navigate, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom'
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth'

//check if the user is logged in or not
//this is a component that will help us protect our routes
const RequireAuth = () =>{
    const {auth} = useAuth()
    const location = useLocation()
   console.log(auth)
     return(
        auth?.username ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to='/login' state={{from: location}} replace/>
     )
}
export default RequireAuth

//PersistLogIn

const PersistLogIn = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const refresh = useRefreshToken()

    const {auth, persist} = useAuth()

    useEffect(()=>{

        const refreshTokenVerify = async () =>{
            try{
               
               await  refresh()
            }
            catch(err){
                console.error(err)
            }
            finally{
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        }

        !auth?.accessToken ? refreshTokenVerify() : setIsLoading(false)
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(`isLoading: ${isLoading}`)
        console.log(`aTh: ${JSON.stringify(auth?.accessToken)}`)
    },[isLoading])

  return (
    <>
                {isLoading
                    ? <p>Loading...</p>
                    : <Outlet />
            }
    </>
  )
}

export default PersistLogIn





//BackEnd

//authController

const handleUserLogIn = async (req, res)=>{
    const {username, password} = req.body
    if(!username || !password) return res.status(400).json({'message':'username or password is required'})//Bad Request

    const foundUserData = await User.findOne({username}).exec();
    console.log(foundUserData) 

    if(!foundUserData) return res.sendStatus(401)//Unauthorized

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUserData.password)
    if(!validPassword){
        return res.sendStatus(401)//Unauthorized
    }else{
      //create the JWT
      const accessToken= jwt.sign({'username':foundUserData.username}, 
      process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '30s'})
      const refreshToken= jwt.sign({'username':foundUserData.username}, 
      process.env.REFERESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: '5m'})

      //save refreshToken with current user
      foundUserData.refreshToken = refreshToken
      const result = await foundUserData.save()
      console.log(result)
      
      //create a secured cookie with refreshToken
      res.cookie('jwtToken',refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 300000} ) //secure: true
      
      //res.cookie('token', accessToken, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 20000})

      //Send access Token to user
      res.json({accessToken})
    }
        
}

module.exports={handleUserLogIn}

//refreshTokenController

const handleRefreshToken = async(req, res)=>{
  const cookies = req.cookies
  console.log(cookies.jwtToken)

  if(!cookies?.jwtToken) return res.sendStatus(401)//unauthorized //.jwt
  console.log(cookies.jwtToken)
  const refreshToken = cookies.jwtToken

  const foundUserData2 = await User.findOne({refreshToken}).exec()
  if(!foundUserData2) return res.sendStatus(403)//Forbidden

  //evaluate JWT
  jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFERESH_TOKEN_SECRET, 
     (err, decoded)=>{
        if(err || foundUserData2.username !== decoded.username)return res.sendStatus(403);//forbidden
        //another accessToken is created
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {'username':decoded.username}, 
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, 
        {expiresIn: '30s'}
        )

      res.json({accessToken})
     })
}
module.exports = {handleRefreshToken}
```